# is there a way to use lambda here?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

```
(define ( f x)
  (* 2 x))

(define (mapit n)
  (cond
    [(empty? n) empty]
    [(cons? n)
      (map f (filter odd? n))]))


(check-expect (mapit (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))(list 2 6 10 14))
```

multiplies the filtered elements in this list by 2. Is there a way to use `lambda` here? I know it's not necessary but I am trying to get used to `lambda`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just replace the `f` named function with a `lambda`, which is an anonymous function:

```
(define (mapit n)
  (cond
    [(empty? n) empty]
    [(cons? n)
      (map (lambda (x) (* 2 x))
           (filter odd? n))]))
```

It's easy to see why we can make the replacement above. Just remember that this:

```
(define (f x)
  (* 2 x))
```

… Is equivalent to this:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x) (* 2 x)))
```

… And in the `mapit` procedure we just need to substitute `f` with its corresponding value. In general: you should use a `lambda` when you need a one-shot function - a function that's not going to be used elsewhere. On the other hand, if the function will be reused across several places, then name it and refer to it by name.